# winforms combobox bounded to bindingsource is not displaying selected item

Tags: c#, winforms

I am facing a problem in my combobox which is bounded to binding source.
The problem is it is not displaying the text when i select the combox.but i am getting the selected value.

this is the code of generated in my form designer class.

Here partysource and purchaseOrderSource are bindisng source.party source is binded to object called party and purchaseOrderSource  is binded to object purchaseorder.

```
this.LstSupplier.DisplayMember = "ItemName";
this.LstSupplier.ValueMember = "ItemId";
this.LstSupplier.DataSource = this.partysource;
this.LstSupplier.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", this.purchaseOrderSource, "PartyId", true));            
this.LstSupplier.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.LstSupplier.Name = "LstSupplier";
```

how can i solve this?

Comment: Question is vague at the moment. What is `partysource` ? `purchaseOrderSource`? Post those definitions

Comment: Grant Winney,i am getting the selectedindex,SelectedValue,SelectedItem,but not getting selected text.it is coming as blank.

Comment: Your posted code works.  You need to show us more information.

Comment: grant winney,Itemname and itemid is property of my class

Comment: larstech,which information is needed.

Comment: Anything that duplicates the problem.  So far, you haven't duplicated the problem in the code you posted.  What is partysource?  A List<T>?  A DataTable?  etc.

Comment: partysource is a bindingsource.in my page load i am binding the party source with a list<T>

Comment: You still haven't provided enough information to see the problem.  The code posted works.